# Ender 3 Layer Shifting

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, diy-3d-printer, layer-shifting

I recently got an ender 3.
It was working well for 2 prints. I managed to print two small items which were upgrades for the printer (filament guide and cable clip).
Following this, I tried to print some larger designs and I noticed it began shifting the layers on the x-axis...
How do I fix it? [image]

Comment: Have you made sure that the belt for the x-axis is quite tight?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're sure this is X (left/right, the axis the hotend carriage moves along) and not Y (the axis the bed moves along). Y-axis layer shifts are a lot more common.

Comment: If the layer shifts really are along the X-axis, it's likely that the gantry is not square with the Z-axis (leaning), thereby making the nozzle collide with the print. In addition to squareness, check that all the Z rollers are tight on the Z-axis aluminum extrusions and that there is not any play in the one on the right especially. The places where the gantry bolts onto the plates that hold the Z rollers have a plenty play to mount them non-square, and having this wrong is a common problem. Also, of course, make sure the bed is level (with respect to the nozzle; see general bed leveling info)

Comment: Yes, it is the axis. I will try that too, I saw an upgrade for a z-axis spacer too.